# Plugin migration - calling services help

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

In my Craft 2 plugin my initial init function looked like:

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    if(!extension_loaded('imagick')) {
        PdfThumbnailerPlugin::log("imagick library not found - cannot make pdf thumbnails" , LogLevel::Warning);
        return;
    }

    craft()->on('entries.saveEntry', function(Event $event) {
         craft()->pdfThumbnailer_saveEntry->setThumb($event);
    });

    craft()->on('assets.saveAsset', function(Event $event) {
        PdfThumbnailerPlugin::log("on save asset");
        craft()->pdfThumbnailer_saveAsset->checkAsset($event);
    });

}
```

I cannot understand (due to lack of devchops) or find an example of how to call my functions (which were in service files) in Craft3.

I can see the constants used in the new style 'listener' but have no idea what or where these are referenced in the v3 docs.

```
    // Register our site routes
    Event::on(
        UrlManager::class,
        UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_URL_RULES,
        function (RegisterUrlRulesEvent $event) {
            $event->rules['siteActionTrigger1'] = 'pdfthumbnailer/save-entry';
            $event->rules['siteActionTrigger2'] = 'pdfthumbnailer/save-asset';
        }
    );
```

My plugin in craft 2 would create a thumbnail from the first page of a PDF asset.

UPDATE:
SO i eventually made some progress with :

```
Pdfthumbnailer::$plugin->SaveEntry->setThumb($event);
```

Except this kept saying it could not find service method:

```
Getting unknown property: joomkit\pdfthumbnailer\Pdfthumbnailer::SaveEntry
```

It turns out that the method 'SaveEntry' only was found when named 'saveEntry'. Why would this be the case? (excuse pun)

Comment: `SaveEntry` in your case is the name of a component. There is a function `registerComponents` you should check what parameters you pass to this function

Comment: Brilliant Robin. Its defined in composer extra ->components->saveEntry
Is this the norm for service declaration now?

Comment: I suggest you to remove that part during development

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer the question fully without seeing your plugin code, but I'd suggest you generate your plugin scaffolding with [pluginfactory.io](https://pluginfactory.io/) to see how it all fits together.

It's also helpful to look at a existing plugin that works; here's one I wrote that's pretty simple, and should be easy to follow: [FastCGI Cache Bust](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-fastcgicachebust)

Roughly, you'd do something like:

```
PluginClass::getInstance()->serviceName->methodName();
```

Or if you do it the pluginfactory.io way:

```
PluginClass::$plugin->serviceName->methodName();
```

Comment: Thanks andrew. Ironically I did use pluginfactory but was wondering what the on entry save  event  looks like in craft3. will dig in